# jQuery : hide rows in table based on column data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML Table and it has a HTML button underneath it as shown below.

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button">Hide A</button>
```

Is it possible to do hide all  rows that belong to Company A when I click on that button ?

I know I can hide elements using `$(selector).hide()` but I am not sure how  I can select/hide only certain rows based on some value ?

Comment: what have you tried to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based only on the provided sample html. Within your click handler, using the correct selector to find the first td of each tr and then looping over each to perform decision logic would work:

```
$("tr td:first-child").each(function(index){
    if($(this).text() === "A") {
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add a class to each row with a company identifier:

```
 <tr class="company-a">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
```

Then in your jQuery you can go something like:

```
$('.company-a').hide()
```

I have added a fiddle to show how this could work: https://jsfiddle.net/qmrkdesf/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

(Note that selecting elements by their tag names is bad practice. You should add some data attributes instead, and then use `$('[data-my-table]')` and such.)

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', () => {
    $('table td:first-child')
      .filter((_, cell) => $(cell).text() === 'A')
      .closest('tr')
      .hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button">Hide A</button>

</body>
</html>
```